# Using PHP to access elements from Facebook Graph API Array

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, associative-array

I know this is probably a simple question, but I have been struggling with this for a few hours without any solution. I calling the Facebook Graph API and getting a result like so:

```
{
   "og_object": {
      "id": "1060581720684416",
      "description": "It's\u00a0a chance to donate to your local shelter, volunteer with animals or simply cuddle up to your furry friend.",
      "title": "National Dog Day 2016 Quotes: 15 Sayings And Photos Celebrating Man's Best Friend",
      "type": "article",
      "updated_time": "2016-08-26T19:26:39+0000"
   },
   "share": {
      "comment_count": 0,
      "share_count": 481
   },
   "id": "http://www.ibtimes.com/national-dog-day-2016-quotes-15-sayings-photos-celebrating-mans-best-friend-2407163"
}
```

I am only interested in accessing the "share_count" and "comment_count" values from this array. Here is the PHP I am trying to use:

```
$searchTopFBCount = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $thisFBLink . '?access_token=xxxxxxxxxx';
$getthisContents = file_get_contents($searchTopFBCount);
$jsonTopFBCount = json_decode($getthisContents,true);
$jsonTopShares = $jsonTopFBCount[0][share]->share_count;
$jsonTopComments = $jsonTopFBCount[0][share]->comment_count;
$jsonTopFBTotal = $jsonTopShares + $jsonTopComments;
```

No matter what I try, I can't seem to get any values for `$jsonTopShares` and `$jsonTopComments`. Any help anyone can give me with this problem would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you get any error or just empty values?

Comment: It seems to be an object, not an array. Why are you using [0] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone mentioned in the comments, I'm not sure why you're using `[0]` as your data isn't in a nested array. You're also trying to access the array properties like they're objects.

Try this instead:

```
$jsonTopShares = $jsonTopFBCount['share']['share_count'];
$jsonTopComments = $jsonTopFBCount['share']['comment_count'];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was just totally overlooking that!